# Inserting values into objects from a function

Tags: c++, function, object, call, blackjack

I make a blackjack game in c ++, and I have a function that distributes cards to the house player and the other players, this function gets an object that is the deck of cards, an object that is the house player, and an array of objects that are the other players, the problem is that when you exit the function, the object Does not contain the cards dealt to him in the function, compared to the array of objects (other players) as it contains

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NumberOfPlayers 1

class Card {

public:
    int CardValue;
    string type;
    string RoyalCard = "";

    friend class Pack;
    friend class Player;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Card c);
};

class Pack {

public:
    Card P[13][4];
    bool visible[13][4];

    Pack() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                visible[i][j] = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                P[i][j].CardValue = i + 1;

                switch (j) {
                case 0: {
                    P[i][j].type = "Heart";
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    P[i][j].type = "Diamond";
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    P[i][j].type = "Clover";
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    P[i][j].type = "Leaf";
                    break;
                }
                }

                switch (P[i][j].CardValue) {
                case 1: {
                    P[i][j].RoyalCard = "Ace";
                    break;
                }
                case 11: {
                    P[i][j].CardValue = 10;
                    P[i][j].RoyalCard = "Prince";
                    break;
                }
                case 12: {
                    P[i][j].CardValue = 10;
                    P[i][j].RoyalCard = "Queen";
                    break;
                }
                case 13: {
                    P[i][j].CardValue = 10;
                    P[i][j].RoyalCard = "King";
                    break;
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Pack p);
};

class Player {
    
public:
    string Name;
    int Points = 0;
    int Money = 200;
    int NumberOfPlayerCards = 0;
    Card PlayerCards[6];

    Player() {
        cout << "Enter player name: ";
        cin >> Name;
        cout << "\n";
    }

    Player(string name, int money) {
        Name = name;
        Money = money;  
    }

    int ChooseValueOfAce() {

        int Ace;
        
        cout << "Select the value of your Ace card: 1/11\n";
        do {
            cin >> Ace;
        }       
        while (Ace != 1 && Ace != 11);

        cout << "\n";

        return Ace;
    }

    friend iostream& operator<<(iostream& out, Player p);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Card c) 
{
    if (c.CardValue == NULL || c.type == "") {
        return cout;
    }

    else {
        if (c.RoyalCard != "") {
            cout << c.RoyalCard << " " << c.type << " ";        
        }
        else {
            cout << c.CardValue << " " << c.type << " ";
        }
    }
    return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Pack pack)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            
            cout << pack.P[i][j] << " ";
            
            if (pack.visible[i][j]) {
                cout << "True\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "False\n";
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";

    return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Player player) {

    cout << "Name: " << player.Name << "\n";

    if (player.NumberOfPlayerCards > 0) {

        cout << "Cards: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < player.NumberOfPlayerCards; i++) {
        cout << player.PlayerCards[i] << "       ";

        if (i == player.NumberOfPlayerCards - 1) {
            cout << "\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n       ";
        }
    }
    }

    cout << "Points: " << player.Points << "\nMoney: " << player.Money << "$" << "\n\n";

    return out;
}

Pack DividingCards(Pack pack, Player players[], Player cp) {

    srand(time(0));
    
    int chooseCardValue;
    int chooseCardType;

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        chooseCardValue = rand() % 13;
        chooseCardType = rand() % 4;

        if (pack.visible[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType]) {
            cp.PlayerCards[j] = pack.P[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType];
            cp.NumberOfPlayerCards++;
            pack.visible[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType] = false;
            if (cp.PlayerCards[j].CardValue != 1) {
                cp.Points += cp.PlayerCards[j].CardValue;
            }
        }
        else {
            j--;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            chooseCardValue = rand() % 13;
            chooseCardType = rand() % 4;

            if (pack.visible[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType]) {
                players[i].PlayerCards[j] = pack.P[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType];
                players[i].NumberOfPlayerCards++;
                pack.visible[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType] = false;

                if (players[i].PlayerCards[j].CardValue != 1) {
                    players[i].Points += players[i].PlayerCards[j].CardValue;
                }
            }
            else {
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    return pack;
}

Pack TakingAnotherCard(Pack pack, Player player) {

    char x = NULL;

    while (x != 'Y' && x != 'N') {
        cout << "Do you want to take another card?\nPress: Y/N\n";
        cin >> x;
    }

    if (x == 'N') {
        return pack;
    }
    else {
        srand(time(0));

        int chooseCardValue;
        int chooseCardType;

        while (1) {
            chooseCardValue = rand() % 13;
            chooseCardType = rand() % 4;

            if (pack.visible[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType]) {
                player.PlayerCards[player.NumberOfPlayerCards] = pack.P[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType];
                pack.visible[chooseCardValue][chooseCardType] = false;

                if (player.PlayerCards[player.NumberOfPlayerCards].CardValue != 1) {
                    player.Points += player.PlayerCards[player.NumberOfPlayerCards].CardValue;
                }
                player.NumberOfPlayerCards++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return pack;
}

int main() {

    Player cp("CPU", 500);
    Player players[NumberOfPlayers];
    Pack pack;
    pack = DividingCards(pack, players, cp);

    cout << pack;
    cout << cp;

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
    cout << players[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < players[i].NumberOfPlayerCards; j++) {
            if (players[i].PlayerCards[j].CardValue == 1) {
                players[i].Points += players[i].ChooseValueOfAce();

                for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
                    cout << players[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
        pack = TakingAnotherCard(pack, players[i]);
        cout << players[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code that doesn't seem relevant to the issue. Anyway, just skimming it, it seems you're passing things like "Player" to a function by value, that means it will be copied. If you want to modify it inside the function you need to pass it by reference like `Pack DividingCards(Pack pack, Player players[], Player& cp)` (notice the ampersand)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly is not working? What is the output you're expecting? `srand(time(0));` should generally only be called once at the beginning of your program. Turn up your compiler warning level and pay attention to them.

Comment: `Pack TakingAnotherCard(Pack pack, Player player)` this function should use reference parameters too.

Answer (score 0):

This is just bashed out at the keyboard but `Card` is a value type. You also appear to be duplicating the cards that are in the pack (held by the dealer) and the player's cards (visible on the table). Maybe you can start here:

```
/* This code is very incomplete
 */

class Card
{
public:
    enum Type { Heart, Diamond, Clover, Leaf, NumberOfTypes };
    enum Value { Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Prince, Queen, King, NumberOfValues };

    Card(Type t, Value v)
    : m_type(t), m_value(v)
    {
    }

    Type type() const { return m_type; }
    Value value() const { return m_value; }
};

class Dealer
{
public:
    /** \brief Give the initial set of cards to the players
      */
    void dealTo(std::vector<Player>& players);

    /** \brief Move a random card from the dealer's pack into the player's pack
     */
    void giveCardTo(Player& player);

private:
    std::set<Card> generatePack()
    {
        std::set<Card> pack;

        for(int type = 0; type < NumberOfTypes; ++type)
            for(int value = 0; value < NumberOfValues; ++value)
                pack.insert(Card((Card::Type)type, (Card::Value)value));

        return pack;
    }
};

class Player
{
public:
    /** \brief Add the card to our own pack
     */
    void receive(Card card);

    /** \brief The points are calculated based on the current pack
     */
    int points() const;

private:
    std::set<Card> pack;
};
```

Thus, there are always only 52 cards. To give a player a card you move a card from the set representing the pack of the dealer into the set representing a player's hand. This also follows the [Tell, Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) philosophy because the dealer passes a card to a player in Blackjack. A player does not take a card.